# Ubuntu 20.4 - Fail to boot after install Windows10 as Dual Boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

Ubuntu 20.04 is installed on `/dev/sda`, on a SSD drive. All worked OK.

On `/dev/sdc2` Windows10 was installed successfully. Both OS's are **UEFI**.

`grub` was not loaded on boot, so to boot `Ubuntu` or `Windows10`, was able after boot drive was changed in BIOS setup.

To try to fix it, following [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu).

After installing `boot-repair` which seemed to be successful, I got an error saying that `/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod not found` and from now on, boot process stopped and stayed in `grub Rescue` mode.

The only thing I can do is to change boot drive to `Windows10 Bootmanager` at BIOS, which loads Windows10 OK.

How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not recocnize EXT4 partitions, on which Ubuntu is installed. The ideal way to dualboot Windows and Ubuntu is to install Windows first, then Ubuntu will give you the option to install alongside Windows.

Comment: Ubuntu was installed 2 years before :) , but GRUB and flag are placed in Ubuntu's partition- so I don't understand your answer

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't install grub for the i386-pc platform in UEFI systems (It should be x86_64-efi). If you are 100% sure you booted the installation in UEFI mode, did you select to mount the EFI partition? If not, that could be the reason.